# Can't connect to Tor. Loading fails

Tags: help

```
10/26/2016 20:15:15 PM.600 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 85%: Finishing handshake with first hop  
10/26/2016 20:15:23 PM.200 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150  
10/26/2016 20:15:23 PM.200 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections.   
10/26/2016 20:15:23 PM.200 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150   
10/26/2016 20:15:24 PM.200 [NOTICE] Delaying directory fetches: DisableNetwork is set.   
10/26/2016 20:15:27 PM.000 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections.   
10/26/2016 20:15:27 PM.000 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections.   
10/26/2016 20:15:27 PM.000 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections.   
10/26/2016 20:15:27 PM.000 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150   
10/26/2016 20:15:36 PM.300 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 85%: Finishing handshake with first hop. (DONE; DONE; count 10; recommendation warn; host 379BD6B5EC586D5DFAC29D67F04FA0F6C8985264 at 158.69.210.73:9001)   
10/26/2016 20:15:36 PM.300 [WARN] 11 connections have failed:   
10/26/2016 20:15:36 PM.300 [WARN]  10 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE   
10/26/2016 20:15:36 PM.300 [WARN]  1 connections died in state connect()ing with SSL state (No SSL object)   
10/26/2016 20:15:39 PM.800 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150   
10/26/2016 20:15:39 PM.800 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections.   
10/26/2016 20:15:39 PM.800 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150   
10/26/2016 20:15:39 PM.800 [NOTICE] Delaying directory fetches: DisableNetwork is set.
```

Comment: This looks like DPI-based censorship. It's able to send the TLS ClientHello but fails to get a ServerHello back. You should try using pluggable transports, try obfs4 and meek.